# Uploading an InfoPath form programmatically

Tags: 2010, development, infopath

I know how to upload the published xsn InfoPath form, but when I try to open it, the form can't find its code behind assembly dll. Does anyone know how to add that? I know it gets put in hive 14 folder at FT-01-\version #.

Do I have to manually find that folder and place the dll in there? Or is there a way I can upload the dll along with the form?

Here is my code so far:

```
            FormsService localFormsService;
            SPFarm localFarm = SPFarm.Local;

            try
            {
                FormTemplate temp = new FormTemplate();
                localFormsService = localFarm.Services.GetValue<FormsService>(FormsService.ServiceName);

                localFormsService.FormTemplates.UpgradeFormTemplate(@"C:\PublishedForms\My Form.xsn",  FormTemplateCollection.UpgradeType.Overwrite);                    

                SPWebApplication webApplication = SPContext.Current.Site.WebApplication;
                SPSiteCollection siteCollections = webApplication.Sites;

                FormTemplateCollection fCol = localFormsService.FormTemplates;

                foreach (FormTemplate f in fCol)
                {
                    if (f.Name == "My Form")
                        f.Activate(siteCollections[0]);
                }                    
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { }
```

Here is the error I get when I try to open the form from my site collection.

> "Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Template\Features\FT-01-6c9edb80-4be2-73f2-3ef4-bb647484b323\MyForm.dll' or one of its dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains server-side code which will run only in Infopath web browser opened in browser, i.e. [through IPFS Sharepoint Server Infopath Form Service](http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/23828/82714.aspx#82714).

The problem is that Infopath browser form may be tried to be opened both in browser and in Infopath client/Filler. The latter is default behavior which you must avoid/prevent.

Though, in my experience even after changing in form library Advanced Settings the **Opening Documents in the Browser** from default "Use the server default (Open in the client application)" to "Open in the Browser",

[image: Opening Documents in the Browser]

as well as marking "**Enable this form to be filled out by using a browser**" in Publishing wizard of Infopath browser form template

[image: "Enable this form to be filled out by using a browser" in in Publishing wizard of Infopath browser form template]

the Infopath **Web Browser Form** can still be explicitly tried to be opened in client through context menu:

[image: Edit in browser - Edit in Microsoft Infopath context choices]

as well as the links to existing XML data forms or "Add new document" in a sharepoint form library

[image: "Add new document" in a sharepoint form library]

are still being opened in client/filler in Internet Explorer (and in browser if opened, for example, in Mozilla Firefox).

I am not quite sure how to control this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The code behind is contained in the xsn file, which is also a CAB file.

Comment: That's what I thought but I am still getting a "Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Template\Features\FT-01-6c9edb80-4be2-73f2-3ef4-bb647484b323\MyForm.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. "
Error when I try to open it